# How can I restrict access to location in nginx based on node.js handler

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a endpoint that looks like this.

`location / { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8086; client_max_body_size 1024M; }`

The problem is, that I don't want the compiled JS code to be leaked in public. For that, I want to have an authentication location, and I want to restrict access to main location based on my backend handler that will check for auth token.

How can I set a handler for a location that will check for token before giving access to the location?

I look for something like this:

`location / { proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8086; handler http://127.0.0.1/authCheck; }`